# Does this curve have a minimum?

Tags: calculus, optimization, graphing-functions

I have a question about the function $f(x)$ where $ f: [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is given by:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 5-x, & 0\leq x<4\\   2+x, & x\geq4\end{cases}$$

I would have thought the minimum would be 1 as that is the limit from the left as x approaches 4,
Can a limit not be a minimum?

Any clarification would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: graph on desmos. There is a discontinuity at 4.

Comment: Try to see what happens if you plug in 10,100,1000 and so on

Comment: Hi andijivie, I understand there is no max but surely there is a minimum as the graph never goees to -infinity?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}2-x=-\infty$

Comment: If you plug in those numbers you find $f(10)=-8$, $f(100)=-98$, $f(1000)=-998$ and so on.

Comment: sorry, made a mistake should be x+2,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
         5 - x, & 0 \leq x < 4\\
         2 + x, & x \geq 4
         \end{cases}
$$
assumes each value in the interval $(1, 5]$ on the interval $[0, 4)$ and assumes each value in the interval $[6, \infty)$ on the interval $[4, \infty)$.  Therefore, its range is $(1, 5] \cup [6, \infty)$.  At no point in its domain is the value of the function equal to $1$.  Therefore, $1$ is not a [minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima).  It is a lower bound, meaning that for each $x$ in the domain, $f(x) > 1$.  In fact, it is the greatest lower bound (or [infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum)) since $1$ is the largest number that is a lower bound for the range.